# Convert multiple if statements to dispatch functions

Tags: java, function, java-8, dispatch

I am struggling to find a way to dispatch this to functions in java8

```
    Person p = registry.getPerson();

    if (field == Field.LASTNAME) {
        p.setLastName(str);
    }
    if (field == Field.FIRSTNAME) {
        p.setFirstName(str);
    }
    if (field == Field.MIDDLENAME) {
        p.setMiddleName(str);
    }
```

My idea is to use some kind of function dispatch table to replace the if statements in the case of more cases:

```
Map<Integer, Function> map = new HashMap<Integer, Function>  
static {
    map.put(1, new Function<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public Object apply(String str) {
            person.setLastName(str);
            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

But the code cannot compile, because i need to pass the person object some place. Anyone knows a pattern for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing `Function<String,String>`, you can store `BiFunction<Person,String,String>` and pass the `Person` instance in as a parameter.

```
Map<Integer, BiFunction<Person,String,String>> map = 
        new HashMap<Integer, BiFunction<Person,String,String>>();  
static {
    map.put(1, (person, str)->person.setLastName(str));

}
```

In the interest of simplicity, you could also just store a `List` of the functions, if you're just going to index them by an integer, it's faster for random access and makes for less complicated generic code:

```
List<BiFunction<Person,String,String>> list = new ArrayList<BiFunction<Person,String,String>>();  
static {
    list.add((person, str)->person.setLastName(str));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Field is an enum, you can add `BiConsumer<Person,String>` as an enum field:

```
class Person {

    static enum Field {
        FIRSTNAME(Person::setFirstName),
        MIDDLENAME(Person::setMiddleName),
        LASTNAME(Person::setLastName)
        ;

        private BiConsumer<Person, String> setter;

        private Field(BiConsumer<Person, String> setter) {
            this.setter = setter;
        }
    }

    public void set(Field field, String str) {
        field.setter.accept(this, str);
    }

    ......
}
```

Comment: I prefer this, but I assumed that his `Field.X` references were constants since he `Map`ped them to `Integer`s.

Comment: I might refactor my code to use enums, as this implementation looks cleaner